# Hadoop MapReduce implementation of shortest PATH in a graph, not just the distance

Tags: graph, hadoop, mapreduce, shortest-path

I have been looking for "MapReduce implementation of Shortest path search algorithms".

However, all the instances I could find "computed the shortest distance form node x to y", and none actually output the "**actual shortest path like x-a-b-c-y**".

As for what am I trying to achieve is that I have graphs with hundreds of 1000s of nodes and I need to perform frequent pattern analysis on shortest paths among the various nodes. This is for a research project I am working on.

It would be a great help if some one could point me to some implementation (if it exists) or give some pointers as to `how to hack the existing SSSP implementations to generate the paths along with the distances`.

Comment: Have you looked into the implementation of Djikstra's or A* to understand how they work?  They are both really, really simple, and once you understand them, doing what you're asking is trivial.

Comment: Are you limited to base hadoop?  There are several open source packages on top of hadoop (Giraph and Golden Orb) that specialize in graph algorithms, although I don't follow that segment too much.

The idea is that instead of writing mappers and reducers you implement your algorithm as classes that represent nodes and messages that match up with the graph's edges.

Comment: There is also Apache Hama ;) BTW GoldenORB is dead.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: I did look atthose implementations and was kind of hoping that someone would point me to ideas on how to tweak them to get what I want, can you help me with a bit more details maybe we can consider the explanation given here as I am a beginner with hadoop http://famousphil.com/blog/2011/06/a-hadoop-mapreduce-solution-to-dijkstra%E2%80%99s-algorithm/

Comment: @ThomasJungblut & Chris Gerken: I did look at giraph which appeared to be in very nascent stages and hama as well, since I am starting off with hadoop switching to pregel kind of a paradigm seemed a little overwhelming, however I would be willing to spend time on it if its worth.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: Sorry if I left anything off the list.  As I said I don't follow that segment.  I was really just asking if the solution has to be pure hadoop.  From what gather from these comments, Angshu, you're probably better off sticking with pure hadoop and following Thomas' answer below.

Comment: No problem, you can fit this problem to MapReduce. But it will be a much more resource hungry way of crunching the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Basically these implementations work with some kind of messaging. So messages are send to HDFS between map and reduce stage.

In the reducer they are grouped and filtered by distance, the lowest distance wins. When the distance is updated in this case, you have to set the vertex (well, some ID probably) where the message came from.

So you have additional space requirement per vertex, but you can reconstruct every possible shortest path in the graph.

Based on your comment:

yes probably

> I will need to write another class of the vertex object to hold this
>   additional information. Thanks for the tip, though it would be very
>   helpful if you could point out where and when I can capture this
>   information of where the minimum weight came from, anything from your blog maybe :-)

Yea, could be a quite cool theme, also for Apache Hama. Most of the implementations are just considering the costs not the real path. In your case (from the blog you've linked above) you will have to extract a vertex class which actually holds the adjacent vertices as `LongWritable` (maybe a list instead of this split on the text object) and simply add a parent or source id as field (of course also `LongWritable`). 
You will set this when propagating in the mapper, that is the for loop that is looping over the adjacent vertices of the current key node.

In the reducer you will update the lowest somewhere while iterating over the grouped values, there you will have to set the source vertex in the key vertex by the vertex that updated to the minimum.

You can actually get some of the vertices classes here from my blog:
[Source](http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.de/2011/04/graph-exploration-with-hadoop-mapreduce.html)
or directly from the repository:
[Source](http://code.google.com/p/hama-shortest-paths/source/browse/#svn/trunk/hama-gsoc/src/de/jungblut/mapreduce/graphSource)

Maybe it helps you, it is quite unmaintained so please come back to me if you have a specific question.

Here is the same algorithm in BSP with Apache Hama:

https://github.com/thomasjungblut/tjungblut-graph/blob/master/src/de/jungblut/graph/bsp/SSSP.java

Comment: yes probably I will need to write another class of the vertex object to hold this additional information. Thanks for the tip, though it would be very helpful if you could point out where and when I can capture this information of where the minimum weight came from, anything from your blog maybe :-)

Comment: Wow! Thanks. So I am thinking this: in the map phase every active node (the nodes that are neither closed nor visited) passes on 2 pieces of information to its neighbors: 1) the cost of reaching the neighbor as per its information and 2) the shortest path that it knows of (basically the list you suggested with its own id appended to the list), and of course set the neighbor's status to "visited", sort of dirt bit. Then in the reduce phase all the nodes with visited status will scan for the minimum cost and save the corresponding path. 

Can you please point out if there are any obvious errors?

Comment: Also since I am dealing with digraphs, probably I will have to tweak the algorithms a little for termination conditions, will try to implement this thought and see where I end up. Meanwhile thanks a lot for all the helpful inputs!!!

Comment: Your understanding looks good to me. No problem, hope it helps you ;)